# When enemy goes out of screen game is lost

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to make that when enemy passes the screen game is lost without adding ground and collision

```
        if event.time - timeLastEnemy >= math.random(600, 1000) then
        -- Randomly position it on the top of the screen
        enemy = display.newImageRect("assets/graphics/enemy.png",98,150)
        enemy.x = math.random(halfEnemyWidth, display.contentWidth - halfEnemyWidth)
        enemy.y = -enemy.contentHeight
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
local function runtimeStuff()
  if enemy.y > 500 then
  --lose game
  end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",runtimeStuff)
```

Hope this helps